# No Prime icon in panel after activating nvidia drivers

Tags: icons, panel, nvidia-prime

I just installed a fresh copy of Xubuntu 16.04. After making it up-to-date and installing the additional drivers, nvidia version 340.96. I can switch profiles from nvidia or intel just by using "nvidia x server settings". However I wanna do this in the panel and I've no idea how to add it.

Can someone help me out?